# Drawable using Stroke only on the rightside of the solid

Tags: android, xml, drawable

How would I use a stroke on only the right side of my drawable WITHOUT using insets?

[image]

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:shape="rectangle">
            <size
                android:width="20dp"/>
            <solid android:color="@color/colorWhite" />
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="@color/colorPink">
            </stroke>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

**Edit:** Cannot use negative insets because of overlap issue
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="#ff0000" />
    </shape>
</item>

<item android:right="2dp">
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
    </shape>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

or use padding:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="#ff0000" />
        <padding android:right="1dp"/>
    </shape>
</item>

<item>
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
    </shape>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

or:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="#ffffff"/>
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:gravity="right">
    <shape>
        <size android:width="1dp"/>
        <solid android:color="#ff0000"/>
    </shape>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

or:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:bottom="-2dp"
    android:left="-2dp"
    android:top="-2dp">
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
        <stroke
            android:width="1dp"
            android:color="#ff0000" />
    </shape>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: As I said above I cannot use insets, because negative will cause problems https://imgur.com/xvdckVy

Comment: Sorry I didn't notice it, I fixed my code, you can check it :-)

Comment: Is it possible to draw a line with padding instead?

Comment: When I use this, I need to add <item android:width="15dp"> but my device is less than 23 API

Comment: I collected some solutions and updated my answer, you can check it, "attribute width is only used in api level 23 and higher", you should find some other ways instead <item android:width="15dp">.

Comment: It didn't work for me, but you provided some great answers that would work for other people :) Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by drawing a pink layer and then, drawing a white layer `1dp` distant from the right border:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <!-- Pink layer -->
    <item android:width="20dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/colorWhite" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <!-- white layer. It'll cover the pink layer except the last dp -->
    <item android:right="1dp" android:width="19dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/colorWhite" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

Maybe, you can adjust

Comment: doesn't that cause overdraw?